# typescript cannot find name 'provide'.ts(2304) error app.module.ts

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have a problem when i declare interceptor in app.module.ts in angular 11. I have visual studio code ide.

[image]

I had install types

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

and modify my tsconfig.json. Anyone can i help me to resolve this compilation error ?

I have typescript 4.0.2 version

Comment: You should put array of **objects** to providers property. `providers: [{...}, {...}]`

Comment: Hi @yurzui, very thanks, your solution works

Answer (score 5):

As Yurzui said, providers, expect an array of objects, so
change and try:

```
providers:[{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: JwtInterceptor,
  multi: true
}]
```

Comment: Hi @If Guido, effectivly ,Yurzui's solution works fine. very thanks to you also.